# Azure Function ARM Deployment with listkeys results in BadRequest Error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I have a simple ARM template that deploys two Azure Functions, an App Service Plan and a Storage Account:

[image]

The only "special" thing is, that the function `function-key-issue-two` adds the **default host key** from the function `function-key-issue-one` as an app setting:

```
"FunctionOneKey": "[listkeys(concat(variables('functionTwoAppId'), '/host/default/'),'2016-08-01').functionKeys.default]",
```

If I deploy this template to a *new* resource group, it works the first time. Every subsequent deployment fails with a **Bad Request** Error on the Resource **function-key-issue-one/default**:

[image]

This is how the operation details looks like:

```
{
    "Code": "BadRequest",
    "Message": "Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime.",
    "Target": null,
    "Details": [
        {
            "Message": "Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime."
        },
        {
            "Code": "BadRequest"
        },
        {
            "ErrorEntity": {
                "Code": "BadRequest",
                "Message": "Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime."
            }
        }
    ],
    "Innererror": null
}
```

If I remove the `FunctionOneKey` App Setting, the deployment works. Also If I don't specify the App Setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`, the deployment also works.

The function code is deployed later using the `AzureFunctionApp@1` Azure DevOps Task as a Zip package (that is why I set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `1`).

---

**How to reproduce:**

The ARM template I am using is available [here](https://gist.github.com/mjisaak/d335447be4b6e25ce718f8fcc461afcf). 
You can deploy it using. e. g. the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName 'function-key-issue-rg' -TemplateFile "D:\sources\issues\functionDeployment\azuredeploy.json" -name "azuredeploy-$(New-Guid)"
```

---

**Update 1:**

The reason for the `ServiceUnavailable` error is probably because Kudu adds a web.config with a rewrite rule (because I use WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE but don't have deployed the function):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name = "Site Unavailable" stopProcessing = "true">
                    <match url = ".*" />
                    <action type = "CustomResponse" statusCode = "503" subStatusCode = "0" statusReason = "Site Unavailable" statusDescription = "Could not download zip" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My next attempt was to prevent Kudu from doing this by setting
`SCM_TOUCH_WEBCONFIG_AFTER_DEPLOYMENT` to `0` (See: [Don't touch web.config at the end of the deployment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#dont-touch-webconfig-at-the-end-of-the-deployment)). And now it looks like, subsequent deployments *sometimes* succeed:

[image]

But still not a reliable solution :-/.

---

**Update 2:**

- Same issue with the Azure Function Runtime `~2`.
- Switching the Azure Function to Linux also doesn't solve the issue.

---

**Update 3:**

- I opend a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5722) regarding this topic.

---

Any idea what is wrong here? Any workarounds?

Comment: Does the order of deployment of resources is same for when it succeeds? Not sure but have you tried changing the deployment order (using dependsOn) so that function-key-issue-one and all its child resources complete before anything like function-key-issue-two starts?

Comment: Yes, it is the same order for both, error and succeeded deployments. I also already tried using different dependsOn configuration  - without success. However, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

I too have had this problem deploying Function Apps and app settings with ARM templates.

After a back-and-forth with Azure support, we realised that the persistence of the app settings causes a restart of the Function App during deployment, which results in a 503 Service Unavailable while it spins back up. This happens while the deployment is still in progress, which then causes intermittent failures of the `Microsoft.Web/sites/host`. This is also despite the ARM deployment mode being set to `incremental`, which seems to be ignored completely for function app settings.

The Diagnostics Settings of the Function App will list the hard restarts for you and might give some insight into the app setting that caused it.

A suggestion was made from Azure support to separate the app settings into their own `Microsoft.Web/sites/config` section in the ARM template, which `dependsOn` the Function App having finished deployment. I've not tried this yet, and this also goes against what's in the Function App ARM examples, where they are a child `config` resource of a `Microsoft.Web/sites`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change the way you are establishing communication between your functions, and you will also fix your issue. I would recommend you to use Azure Managed Identity to configure the communication between your functions, instead of using the function keys. Please have a look at [this article](https://winsmarts.com/azure-function-with-user-assigned-managed-identity-calling-another-azure-function-securely-df2893f891df) to get more details of what I am saying.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, this is a valid workaround in general. 

However, my Azure Function is getting called multiple times a second. The performance impact of using Managed Identity in this use case is too much.

Comment: You would have an extra request being done to validate your access token, so I don't think this would compromise your performance, honestly. And by doing this, you definitely are following the best practices determined by Microsoft.

Comment: You are right, using managed identity for this is considered to be best practice. But as I said, the performance impact is way too much for my particular use case. I need to find another solution. Also, I am interested in why the deployment fails as it should work - and it works the first time I deploy the template...

Comment: Did you have a look to [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/943). There are people reporting the same exception as you are getting, and apparently is a known issue of outages or slowness when using Linux + Consumption plan. Is that your case on your functions?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, i would suggest to use Azure KeyVault as a default storage for your keys, like described here.
But it seems, that this is related also some issues regarding Appservice and Package Deployments.
Take a look here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10961 and here: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11444.
The documentation also says something like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package

Hope this is helpfull.

Comment: I tried writing the function keys to Azure KeyVault but getting the same error (the listkey function doesn't work). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had, sort of, the same problem in a template, that deployed EventGrid Topic subscribers to a Topic. Precense of the the listkey() function in the json template resulted in the same, very non-descriptive error message.

I've made it work, by updating the ARM template schema to the newest schema supported on Azure: 2019-08-01

Like this:
Top line in the file:
`"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-08-01/deploymentParameters.json#"`,

and inline, in the listkeys function:

```
listkeys(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName')), '/host/default'), '2019-08-01').functionKeys.default)
```

Now, several, subsequent deployments work again, at least for me.

Comment: unfortunately I still get the error after a second deployment :-(. Thanks anyway KatteKylling!

Comment: That's really terrible, because it makes me think that the problem could re-occur at any given time.

Comment: Now, all of a sudden it has stopped working again. Multiple, identical, repeated attempts have now resulted in it working the last time of 6 attempts (fails 5 times out of 6). This is when running the template deployment through a release pipeline.
When repeating the deployment in azure portal, it fails roughly half of the time.
So my solution above is really not a solution, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem recently and contacted the Azure Functions team, and what I understood from them is this: (I am using ARM Template should be same logic to all with different approaches)

1- using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1 must be set before deploying the Zip File, meaning adding dependency between the ZipDeploy with deploying AppSettings.

why?
if this flag is not set at first, the function would take the ZipFile and extract it to `wwroot` folder, leading to empty `SitePackage` folder and breaking the deployment and function. this flag makes the function upload a zip file to a folder in the function shared file system under `data/SitePackage`, with also a `package.txt` that has the name of the related Zip.

this flag aren't supposed to be changed back and forth, because it would break the deployment due to confusing whether it should upload the zip to SitePackages or Extract it to wwroot.

an answer i was given if turning your flag for the first time, it could happen that the first deployment fail, and you need to try again.

2- when using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACAKAGE the function go through a sort of restart, that is written on the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package) you see that after deployment a restart is done.

so the step of "listKeys" could fall on a restart and leading to failure, what you need to do is Add a "wait" step for 1-2 minutes after the function deployed to be sure that everything is done.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I have faced pretty much the same issue. I need to feed the Azure Function which its own host key. After several different test scenarios my conclusion is that there is some delay between the Azure Function App deployment finish and the moment the Host keys are available.

My current *workaround* is to create previously a key in the KeyVault a use this key in two different places:

1. To create a new host key in the Azure Function
2. To feed the Azure Function appsettings

Some sample codes:

**Generating Key in the KeyVault from PS**

```
$secureSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString New-Guid.ToString() -AsPlainText -Force

Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name "azure-function-key" -SecretValue $secureSecret
```

**Create the host key and passing it to the function**

Note that `parameters('internalKey')` would be fed from the KeyVault reference

```
"apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
"kind": "functionapp",
"name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
"location": "[variables('location')]",
"resources": [{
   "dependsOn": ["[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"],
   "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys",
   "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
   "name": "[concat(variables('functionAppName'), '/default/internalkey')]",
   "properties": {
      "name": "internalkey",
      "value": "[parameters('internalKey')]"
   }
},
{
   "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
   "name": "appsettings",
   "type": "config",
   "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
   ],
   "properties": {
      "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
      "HostFunctionKey": "[parameters('internalKey')]"
   }
}]
```

Even in you try the `listKeys` approach with your new host key it won't get the value. First time it will fail and successive times it will get the previous value if it has changed.